# Use `send` to check the existence of an element

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

This code is supposed to take a string as input to check if an element of `page_object` is present. The script has to raise an exception in case it discovers the element, and do nothing if it doesn't.

Example Page Object:

```
span(:partner_flag,          class: 'content-partner-flag')
```

The script:

```
 def check_element_not_exist(page_object)
    page_object = page_object.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
    option = send("#{page_object}")
    if option.exists?
      raise "#{page_object} was not found!"
    end
 end
```

In this case, I use the string `partner_flag` to feed the function and check the element. Watir fails in the line:

```
option = send("#{page_object}")
```

because it needs to find that element in the webpage in order to define `option`. Is there an alternate way of defining `option`, or a different way of making this non-existence check with the `send` functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accessor methods create a method for checking if an element exists.

For example, when you include:

```
span(:partner_flag, class: 'content-partner-flag')
```

Then the method:

```
partner_flag?
```

Is created that returns true if the element exists and false if the element does not.

You could call this method in the `check_element_not_exist` method:

```
def check_element_not_exist(page_object)
  page_object = page_object.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
  exists = send("#{page_object}?")
  if exists
    raise "#{page_object} was found!"
  end
end
```